# Selenium doesn't realize page finished loading

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, loading

I'm writing a trying to **scrape** some data from the following website:

http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/servicos-de-dados/market-data/historico/renda-fixa/

It worked as expected for a while, but now it get stuck in loading the page at line 3.

```
url = 'http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/servicos-de-dados/market-data/historico/renda-fixa/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
```

What is weird is that the page is in fact fully loaded, as I can browse through it without a problem, but chrome keeps showing me a "Connecting..." message in the bottom.

When selenium finally gives up and raises the TimeoutException, the "Connecting..." message dissapears and Chrome understands that the page is in fact fully loaded.

If I try to manually open the link in another tab, it does so in less than a second.

Is there a way I can overide the built in "wait until loaded" and just get to next steps, as everything i need is already loaded?

Comment: That's not a selenium problem - the site is weird. It is loading forever even in manual tests.

Comment: There is a problem with the website. Page loading forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://www.b3.com.br/lumis/portal/controller/html/SetLocale.jsp?lumUserLocale=pt_BR
```

This link loads inifinitely.
Report a bug an ask developers to fix.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to contact them!

Comment: Please accept if the answer solved your question